# Regex does not work for {URL} in the URL rewrite in IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Using URL rewrite in the IIS on windows 10. 
I want to check specific url in the IIS.
Below is the condition I need to check.

1. www.mtl173 **or** http://www.mtl173 **or** http://www.mtl173/ **or** mtl173/ 
   Above all should be valid and should redirect to the given path.

I have checked {URL} so far as following.

```
<rule name="RuleForSite1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="^(http\:\/\/)?(www\.)?mtl173(\/)?$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="www.mtl173/app1/" />
    </rule>
```

**Note:** when I test all the URLs in the IIS, all test passed but when I run the same URL from the browser, it shows me the default IIS page and does not redirect me to the **app1/**.

However, the above does not work and does not redirect the URL to the given path.
Any remediations for the issue I am facing?

Expected result:

When I enter any of the following URL, it should redirect me to the /app1.

1. www.mtl173
2. http://www.mtl173
3. http://www.mtl173/
4. mtl173/

Answer (score 1):

You can use below url rewrite rule.

```
  <rule name="RuleForSite1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.mtl173|mtl173$" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="app1" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mtl173/app1/" />
</rule>
```

[image]

[image]

You can learn about server variable from below links:
[IIS Server Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-dev-reference/server-variables)

Comment: if your issue is solved please mark the post as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Comment: Wait, I am facing another issue ... it redirects me to the app1/login page when I enter completely incorrect URL. Say I am entering URL: http://mtl173/toast/. Here there is no such application (toast) hosted on the IIS. it should show me 404 or 500 or 302 error instead. If you understood my concern and have any solution for that, pls let me know. otherwise, I will ask a new question and mark this answer.

Comment: This is the new question. You could create a new post for a new question. i will try my best to solve your issue.